# Finding the Third Most Recent Value of a Field for Each ID in Each Date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a similar table as below:

```
+----+----------+-------+
| ID | Date     | Value |
+----+----------+-------+
| A  | 20200620 | 150   |
+----+----------+-------+
| A  | 20200621 | 130   |
+----+----------+-------+
| A  | 20200622 | 140   |
+----+----------+-------+
| A  | 20200623 | 200   |
+----+----------+-------+
| B  | 20200622 | 300   |
+----+----------+-------+
| B  | 20200623 | 350   |
+----+----------+-------+
| B  | 20200624 | 400   |
+----+----------+-------+
| B  | 20200625 | 150   |
+----+----------+-------+
```

I need to add a column that for each ID and in each date, it shows the value for two business days prior that date (for example for A in '20200623' it should show the value of the day '20200621'). The output should be something similar to the below:

```
+----+----------+-------+--------------------------+
| ID | Date     | Value | Value_AsoF_TwoDaysBefore |
+----+----------+-------+--------------------------+
| A  | 20200620 | 150   | NULL                        |
+----+----------+-------+--------------------------+
| A  | 20200621 | 130   | NULL                        |
+----+----------+-------+--------------------------+
| A  | 20200622 | 140   | 150                      |
+----+----------+-------+--------------------------+
| A  | 20200623 | 200   | 130                      |
+----+----------+-------+--------------------------+
| B  | 20200622 | 300   | NULL                        |
+----+----------+-------+--------------------------+
| B  | 20200623 | 350   | NULL                        |
+----+----------+-------+--------------------------+
| B  | 20200624 | 400   | 300                      |
+----+----------+-------+--------------------------+
| B  | 20200625 | 150   | 350                      |
+----+----------+-------+--------------------------+
```

Could you please let me know a way to do that? I appreciate all the helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this below option with ROW_NUMBER and Self Joining-

[Demo Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4fb42965e0086f8e0a2ae81dc79f29da)

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date) RN
    FROM your_table
)

SELECT A.ID, A.Value, A.Date, B.Value 
FROM CTE A
LEFT JOIN CTE B ON A.RN = B.RN + 2 AND A.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: You are most welcome @Aliz. Nice to see that it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a row for every date, use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       lag(value, 2) over (partition by id order by date) as Value_AsoF_TwoDaysBefore
from t;
```

If you don't have a value for every day, then use a `left join`:

```
select t.*, tprev.date as Value_AsoF_TwoDaysBefore
from t left join
     t tprev
     on tprev.id = t.id and tprev.date = dateadd(day, -2, t.date) ;
```

Note:  Both of these return `NULL` for the missing values rather than `-`. `NULL`s make much more sense in SQL.